# Se cierra mi aplicación de Android Studio al ejecutarla

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Estaba haciendo una aplicación de Android Studio y a la hora de querer hacer una conexión con la base de datos no me deja ejecutar la aplicación, solo se instala y se cierra.
Ya instale el jtds en la libreria del proyecto, ya la agregué como libreria y todo correcto, incluso hasta ya agregué un archivo de conexión a mi base de datos en SQL

Pero curiosamente al quitarle ese código, ya no ocurre este error, alguien sabe a que se deba?
Esta parte es la que si borro ya no ocurre ese problema

```
    nombre = findViewById(R.id.Nombre)
    Correo = findViewById(R.id.correo)
    servicio = findViewById(R.id.tiposervicio)
    fecha = findViewById(R.id.efecha)
    hora = findViewById(R.id.ehora)
    registrar = findViewById(R.id.button3)
    registrar.setOnClickListener {
        try {
            val addPedido: PreparedStatement = connectSql.dbConn()?.prepareStatement("insert into pedidos values (?,?)")!!
            addPedido.setString(1, nombre.text.toString())
            addPedido.setString(2, Correo.text.toString())
            addPedido.setString(3, servicio.text.toString())
            addPedido.setString(4, fecha.text.toString())
            addPedido.setString(5, hora.text.toString())
            addPedido.executeUpdate()

            Toast.makeText(this, "Pedido registrado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } catch (cx: SQLException) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error al ingresar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

De la demás parte no tiene algún problema, por lo antes ya comentado, que si borro solo esta parte se ejecuta tal cual la había diseñado sin ningún problema

Comment: Hola, al decir que se cierra puede ser causado por cientos de razones, es importante revisar el LogCat y agregar el mensaje de error a tu pregunta, si no usas el LogCat puedes estar tratando de solucionar algo durante unas semanas en lugar de unos segundos. Es recomendable siempre revisar el LogCAt

Comment: Solo me sale eso al ejecutal el LogCat:
                                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: findViewById(R.id.Nombre) must not be null

Además de muchos otros errores :(

Comment: Hola Carlos, el mensaje que recibes es claro, el problema no está en el código que muestras, sino donde instancias las variables que se manejan ahí, **nombre = findViewById( R.id.Nombre )**, sería una de las lineas que fallan, tal vez sea **nombre** y no **Nombre**, tal vez la falta de "**;**", o tal vez no hayas inicializado las variables, si no lo puedes resolver, muestra donde las instancias.

Comment: Deberías agregar toda la clase, ¿en que método estás llamando este código?. Veo también que en la consulta defines 2 parámetros, pero estás enviando 5

Comment: El método en el que estoy llamando al código es .setOnClickListener

Comment: @CarlosAntonioLópezSerrano el problema es el contexto con el que tratas de obtener las referencias de las vistas, te sugiero agregar la clase completa.

Comment: Como se agregaría la clase completa?